# MySQL query performance issue on large tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am having performance issues that are way too large. I'm using PHP script to get data from DB and insert it into another table (the script just runs queries on DB, the one I pasted below to fetch the data and `INSERT` after that). There are two tables that I need to join and output results (fill out the 3rd table), but one of those tables has 3.9M rows of data, and the 2nd one has 416k rows. The problem is I have to use join on type varchar since the tables are not connected in any way (joining through column "name"), since it's the only column they have in common. The table structure is like this :

```
  TABLE streets
  id (PK, int), 
  name varchar(70), 
  postnrid (FK, int)

  TABLE csvstreets 
  id (PK, int),
  lat decimal(12,10),
  lng decimal(12,10),
  streetname varchar(70)
```

Table streets is the one with 3.9M rows and the query looks like this :

```
 SELECT s.id, c.lat, c.lng FROM streets AS s JOIN csvstreets AS c ON LOWER(s.name) = LOWER(c.streetname)
```

The query was running for 2 days straight, and it didn't finish, so I had to cancel it. I have indexed both "name" columns on both tables. On doing `EXPLAIN` on the query it outputs this :

```
# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'c', 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '416240', ''
'1', 'SIMPLE', 's', 'index', NULL, 'name', '73', NULL, '3890226', 'Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)'
```

It looks like "csvstreets" table doesn't use the index I've made for it. I could use any advice since I've tried everything I could find for improving performance on varchar joins.
Also I can't limit the result output since I need all the data it gives back (approx. 380k).
I've added `echo` in the script to see where it stops, but it was just running that `SELECT` query for 2 days, never got to `INSERT` part.

Comment: *I have indexed both "name" columns on both tables* its not useful any more due to `LOWER(s.name)`, Also post explain plan for your query

Comment: Thanks for the info, the "name" columns are different in caption size, e.g one street is like "Balsta 300" and the other is "balsta 301", so I had to use LOWER() there (or UPPER() w/e, it's same)

Comment: you need not use lower() or upper() unless your filed collation ends with _cs (case sensitive) or binary

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the lower()s.  It is keeping the join from using your index and unless you have set case sensitive collation, you don't need it.  It certainly isn't necessary to distinguish "Balsta 300" from "Balsta 301".

If after that your query still isn't completing, show output from all of:

```
show create table streets 
show create table csvstreets
explain SELECT s.id, c.lat, c.lng FROM streets AS s JOIN csvstreets AS c ON s.name=c.streetname
```